# Failed send message to LINE Notify (using HttpsURLConnection POST)

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to send message to LINE notification service by using "Authentication method -> POST https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify" ([LINE Notify API Document](https://notify-bot.line.me/doc/en/))

Here are my codes, and I always get

> Return status code: -1

. Please help me figure out where is the problem ?

***LINENotify.java***

```
package com.example.test3;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class LINENotify {

    private static final String strEndpoint = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify";
    private static final String tokenKEY = "ldO3dTIAjT5OpjWbeZAQtnXhq23poCXcEAvKoTwJHhn";

    public int sendMSG( String message ) {

        int statusCode;
        statusCode = -1;

        try {
            URL url = new URL( strEndpoint );
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization",  "Bearer " + tokenKEY);
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setConnectTimeout(15*1000);
            connection.setDoOutput( true );
            connection.setUseCaches( false );
            connection.connect();

            connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
            connection.setDoInput( true );

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( os, "UTF-8") );

            writer.write( "message=" + message );
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            os.close();

            statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if ( statusCode == 200 ) {
                //
            } else {
                throw new Exception( "Error:(StatusCode)" + statusCode + ", " + connection.getResponseMessage() );
            }
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.test3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText msg;
    Button send;

    LINENotify lineNotify;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        lineNotify = new LINENotify();

        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }// onCreate

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch( v.getId() ) {
            case R.id.button: {
                int statusCode = lineNotify.sendMSG( msg.getText().toString() );
                Toast.makeText(this, "Return status code: " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer !!  Thanks google and people who post their experience and notes.

My failure is

> [Android Developers -> Docs -> Connect to the network](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#java) 
>   To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, don't perform network operations on the UI thread. By default, Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher requires you to perform network operations on a thread other than the main UI thread;

Therefore, I try use AsyncTask to solve the problem.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.test3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText msg;
    Button send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }// onCreate

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch( v.getId() ) {
            case R.id.button: {
                new LINENotify().execute(msg.getText().toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class LINENotify extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private static final String strEndpoint = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify";
        private static final String tokenKEY = "ldO3dTIAjT5OpjWbeZAQtnXhq23poCXcEAvKoTwJHhn";
        String result = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String message = strings[0];

            try {
                URL url = new URL( strEndpoint );
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
                connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization",  "Bearer " + tokenKEY);
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                connection.setConnectTimeout(15*1000);
                connection.setDoOutput( true );
                connection.setUseCaches( false );

                connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
                connection.setDoInput( true );

                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

                writer.write( "message=" + message );
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                connection.connect();

                result = connection.getResponseMessage();

                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException error) {
                // Handles input and output errors
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Some reference links:

[How to fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

[[Android] AsyncTask - 非同步任務](http://aiur3908.blogspot.com/2015/06/android-asynctask.html)

[【Android】AsyncTask - Thread 外的另一選擇](http://oldgrayduck.blogspot.com/2013/01/androidasynctask-thread.html)